# Что делать с проблемой вложенном меню на мобильных версиях?

Tags: html, css

Есть вложенное меню, при наведении на список выводиться его подменю. На мобильной версии нет понятия hover, и чтобы появилось подменю нужно нажать по списку, но при этом происходит переход к ссылке.

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант можно сверстать аналогичное меню, только для мобильников.
По типу - *"кнопка бургер"*, по клику на нее слева выкатывается полное развернутое меню.

#### Костыльный вариант решения

На JS в мобильной версии отмените событие клика на ссылках которые разворачивают меню.

```
$('.menu-link').click(function(Event) {
    Event.preventDefault();
})
```

Теперь есть 2 варианта развития.

1. Добавляем нужную ссылку в выпадающее меню
2. Меняем состояние исходной кнопки (которая разворачивает меню), и по клику на нее отправляем юзера на нужную страницу.

Comment: По сути это не ответ на вопрос. Больше похоже на совет.

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/199062)

Comment: @Владимир по-моему на этот вопрос ничего кроме советов ответить и нельзя)

Comment: @slippyk, исправил

Comment: @Андрей Б После изменения, ответ получился ответом.